# NSCombobox in view-based NSTableView problems

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nscombobox

So I had a view based TableView with 3 text columns. TableView is editable and I can tab across columns to edit. I then decided I needed a `"type"` for each column which could let user select a fixed set of types.

I deleted the `NSTextField` and replaced it with `NSComboBox`. I made sure it was `Behavior="Editable"` in IB and I gave it 3 static values in `IB` as well. Can't get it to work.

First, nothing shows up in the column. I cannot select it. When I hit `<tab>` key while editing it just skips over that column to the next column. It's like TableView does not know it's there.

I must be missing something very fundamental. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Is the combo box inside the table cell view?

Comment: If you don't specify the selected value the combo box is supposed not to show a default value. Try this: In the model declare `@objc dynamic var types = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]` and `@objc dynamic var selectedType : String { return types[0] }`. In Interface Builder bind the `Content` of the combo box to `Table Cell View` >  `objectValue.types` and `Value` to `Table Cell View` > `objectValue.selectedValue`. Does it show `alpha` in all rows. Basically it should work to edit the combo box if editing is enabled. Is `editable` of the column enabled, too (Table Column > ⌥⌘4)?

Comment: "I must be missing something very fundamental."  You are.  You are not showing a single line of code.

Comment: I'm using IB to set the possible values on NSComboBoxCell. My problem was a lack of understanding on how control behaves. I thought since NSComboBox extends NSTextField, and I also want to allow value to be "edited" by typing, I should create and return NSTextField. I now am returning NSComboBox and it works.